# Имитация textarea в html-документе

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Суть задачи такова, что нужно создать на странице блок текста(фиксированного размера с прокруткой) и в дальнейшем проводить с ним манипуляции. Я сверстал это следующим образом: https://jsfiddle.net/skuxdq6j/
Но проблема в том, что я не могу проводить манипуляции с текстом находящимся внутри `textarea`. Т.е. например мне нужно определенные слова выделять следующим образом:

```
<span class="hint-target">text</span>
```

Но `textarea` не позволяет этого делать. Как можно сверстать тоже самое но без использования `textarea` ?

Comment: Используйте обычный div с фиксированой высотой и overflow-y

Comment: @Nilsan  не подскажете как задать эту самую высоту ? В пикселях точно не вариант, ведь тогда верстка не будет отзывчивой.

Comment: Так используйте проценты, не совсем понятно в чём у вас трудность

Comment: @Nilsan в плохих знаниях, и тотальном отвращении к процессу верстки в целом. Впрочем, я уже разобрался, в том числе благодаря вашему комменатрию. Спасибо!